# How do i call specific value by index of array in public static that return an array

Tags: java

```
public static Iterator<Object[]> readData(String FilePath) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Object[]> Myarr= new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    String UserDir= System.getProperty("user.dir");
    CSVReader CSVfileread= new CSVReader(new FileReader(UserDir+ FilePath), '\t');

    CSVfileread.readNext();
    String[] nextLine = null;

    while ((nextLine = CSVfileread.readNext()) != null){
        Myarr.add(new Object [] {nextLine});
    }
    System.out.println("Data file has been read");
    CSVfileread.close();
    return Myarr.iterator();    
}
```

This will read the data file, but i couldn't call this in the script with index of the array. how can i call each Myarr value out side of this public static.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:Selenium]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following,

```
public static ArrayList<Object[]> readData(String FilePath) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Object[]> Myarr= new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    String UserDir= System.getProperty("user.dir");
    CSVReader CSVfileread= new CSVReader(new FileReader(UserDir+ FilePath), '\t');

    CSVfileread.readNext();
    String[] nextLine = null;

    while ((nextLine = CSVfileread.readNext()) != null){
        Myarr.add(new Object [] {nextLine});
    }
    System.out.println("Data file has been read");
    CSVfileread.close();
    return Myarr;    
}
```

//outside you can call like

```
ArrayList<Object[]> output = readData("filepath");
output.get(0) //to get the first value
```